Emulate battery device in yocto QEMU x86-64
I am trying to emulate battery device in the QEMU x86-64. I am building QEMU images using Yocto reference distribution poky, I am building core-image-sato image for the qemux86-64 machine. My goal is to see battery icon in to the QEMU GUI.
As per my understanding, Battery device communicates using acpi so the target needs to have acpi support. I have modified qemux86-64 machine file to have acpi as MACHINE_FEATURES. Now the QEMU needs to have an emulated/fake battery device which can populate the battety device and its information so it can be visible as icon in to the GUI. From exploration I found that below commands (-device option) emulates battery device, But I don't see any battery device in the GUI with these.
QEMU_EXTRAARGS="-device acpi-battery -enable-kvm -display sdl,show-menubar=on -show-cursor" runqemu qemux86-64

QEMU_EXTRAARGS="-device ich9-lpc -enable-kvm -display sdl,show-menubar=on -show-cursor" runqemu qemux86-64

QEMU_EXTRAARGS="-device piix4-acpi -enable-kvm -display sdl,show-menubar=on -show-cursor" runqemu qemux86-64



Can someone help me get a battery device emulated in the Yocto QEMU image?
